# Next.js API: Watermark PDF using query parameters in URL

Tags: api, pdf, next.js

this is my first time testing out Next.js API, I am also quite new to the whole Next.js/React world so bear with me.

The goal for this API route is to trigger an automatic download of a PDF with a custom watermark generated from API URL query parameters like this: `/api/PDFWatermark?id=123&firstname=John&lastname=Doe`

In order to create the watermark I am using [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) and I am using a modified version of [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Hopding/64zajhge/1/) code to watermark my PDF. To generate a modified and downloadable version of the original PDF `pdfDoc` I have tried to create a blob using the `pdfBytes` *after* the watermarking. After the blob is created I thought I could add it to an anchor attached to the DOM.

When commenting out the `blob` and `anchor` code, two errors occur:

1. *ReferenceError: Blob is not defined*
2. *ReferenceError: document is not defined* (possibility because there is no DOM to attach the anchor link)

At this point I am only able to print the `pdfBytes` as json, I am not able to create and download the actual watermarked PDF file.

**Is there a way to auto download the `pdfBytes` as a PDF file when the API is called?**

**UPDATE**

Working code below after changing `modifyPDF` to return a buffer:

```
const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
return Buffer.from(pdfBytes.buffer, 'binary');
```

And:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const filename = "test.pdf";
  const {id, firstname, lastname} = req.query;
  const pdfBuffer = await modifyPDF(firstname, lastname, id);
  res.status(200); 
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');  // Displsay
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+filename);
  res.send(pdfBuffer);
}
```

**WORKING:**

```
import {PDFDocument, rgb, StandardFonts  } from 'pdf-lib';

export async function modifyPDF(firstname, lastname, id) {


    const order_id = id; 
    const fullname = firstname + " " + lastname;

    const existingPdfBytes = await fetch("https://pdf-lib.js.org/assets/us_constitution.pdf").then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);
    const helveticaFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica);


    const watermark = fullname + " (OrderID: " + id + ")";

    
     // Set Document Metadata
     pdfDoc.setSubject(watermark);

     // Get pages
     const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
 
     // Iterate every page, skip first
     //pages.slice(1).forEach(page => {
     pages.forEach(page => {
   
       
       // Get the width and height of the page
       const {
         width,
         height
       } = page.getSize()
 
       // Watermark the page
       page.drawText(watermark, {
             x: 70,
             y: 8,
             size: 10,
             font: helveticaFont,
             color: rgb(0.95, 0.1, 0.1),
       })
     })
  
    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
    return Buffer.from(pdfBytes.buffer, 'binary');
 

}


export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const filename = "test.pdf";
  const {id, firstname, lastname} = req.query;
  const pdfBuffer = await modifyPDF(firstname, lastname, id);
  res.status(200); 
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');  // Displsay
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+filename);
  res.send(pdfBuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `modifyPDF` to return a buffer

```
[...]
    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
    return Buffer.from(pdfBytes.buffer, 'binary');
[...]
```

Let the API return the PDF to the browser through the handler:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {

    const {id, firstname, lastname} = req.query;
    const pdfBuffer = await modifyPDF(firstname, lastname, id);
    res.status(200); 
    
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'); 
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+filename); 
    // Edited as the linked example reports: 
    // res.type('pdf'); // and might not work
    res.send(pdfBuffer);
}
```

Untested but you should get the gist.

[Here's the full example from the library itself](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/issues/163)

Comment: Adding `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'); 
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+filename);` instead of `res.type('pdf');` in addition to `return Buffer.from(pdfBytes.buffer, 'binary');`  Thanks for guiding me in the correct direction!